# Clarification of when the child process' error event fires

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

The [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_error) for a child process' `error` event says the following:

> The `'error'` event is emitted whenever:
>
> 1. The process could not be spawned, or
> 2. The process could not be killed, or
> 3. Sending a message to the child process failed.
>
> See also [`subprocess.kill()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal) and [`subprocess.send()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback).

The first case is met presumably when the `cp.spawn` method fails to spawn the child process successfully.

Is the bit at the bottom suggesting that case 2 and 3 can only be met when the `kill` and `send` methods fail? For instance, if the child process fails to die by other means (like when calling `process.kill`), the `error` event would not be raised. It seems that that would be the case, but I want to confirm.

If I'm never calling `kill` or `send`, can I safely not consider those cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion was correct (I am fairly certain) as how would the OS be able to hook back into Node's code to raise the right event?

Searching for `emit('error',` in Node's child_process [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/625971271b1b9208cd0da53d55f4e5669df3f129/lib/internal/child_process.js#L414) shows you that it can be raised by `cp.spawn`, `kill`, `send` and `disconnect`.

If the process is killed by some other means, then that event could not get raised.